# Background Image is cropped when it is scaled - Is there a way to avoid the image from getting cropped?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, scale

I am currently working on a use case where I set a map as background to canvas and draw over it with zoom option also integrated to it. I am using scale to zoom in and after zoom left and top of the image is getting cropped which is eventually visible after zoom out.

I am loading canvas into a DIV with scroll and the expectation is to avoid image from getting cropped after scale in and scroll should dynamically increase during scale in.

Below is the sample snippet which I have written in plain HTML and JS. In case if anyone has the solution or workaround for the same, please help . Thanks in Advance

NOTE: Even if there is any plugin available in Angular, please comment, as I am using Angular real time and I have created a simple project to test the functionality

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvasId{
background-image:url('https://www.hauteresidence.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1049-Fifth-Avenue-PH3-floor-plan-high-res-e1366734485238-1024x792.jpg');
width: 1300px;
height:1300px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow : auto;
}
</style>
<script>



function myFunction(eventObj) {
 var scale =document.getElementById("canvasId").getAttribute("scl");
 if(scale==undefined)
    scale = 0;
 else 
    scale = parseInt(scale);
    scale += eventObj.deltaY * -0.01;   
  scale = Math.min(Math.max(.125,scale),5);
  document.getElementById("canvasId").setAttribute("scl",scale);
  var check =document.getElementById("canvasId").getAttribute("scl");
  
  if(scale>=1)
   document.getElementById("canvasId").style.transform = "scale("+scale+","+scale+")";
}
</script>
<body>
<div style="width:700px;height:400px;overflow:scroll">
<canvas id ="canvasId"  onWheel="myFunction(event)">
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe adjust the transform-origin: `transform-origin:0 0`

Answer (score 0):

Temani's suggestion of transform-origin is exactly what i needed to solve the 'cropping' behavior.
By default, the transform-origin value is set to '50% 50% 0', or 'center center'. This means that the scaling or Zoom effect we apply emanates from the center of the target(image) and 'bleeds' over the left side of the div more and more.. it becomes unreachable by scrolling and seems 'cropped'.
Setting the transform-origin to:

```
transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;
```

or transform-origin: top left 0px;

changes the anchor point from where the transform/scaling begins, so that it always scales from the left to right and the entire image remains viewable with scrolling.

i made a fiddle showing my result here...

https://jsfiddle.net/trentHarlem/hc5gs3nx/31/

and these were helpful with visualizing whats happening
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trycss3_transform-origin_3d_inuse.htm
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/